# Google Maps authentication fails when I stack Activities

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to use Google Maps in my application. I already setup my Api Key with my Debug Fingerprint and everything is working fine, when i start the MapsActivity as first or as second Activity. But i get an authentication error when I try to start the Activity where I want it to start.

- Starting MapsActivity -> OK
- Starting Activtiy A-> Starting MapActivity -> OK
- Starting Activtiy A-> Starting Activtiy B -> Starting MapActivity -> This fails

This is the MapActivity that I am using:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private EventLocation mLocation;
LatLng sydney;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    MarkerOptions mOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney");
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mOptions.getPosition(), 15));
    mMap.addMarker(mOptions);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

This is from my Manifest:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIza..." />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I am deleting the app before I reinstall it, so I think it is not a cache problem.
In log I just get

> Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably
>   an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

message.

Some people already looked at the code, but they have also no idea what can cause this behaviour.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong or any oppurtunities to get more information in log why it is failing?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that we, too, can look over your code and identify any problems. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for reply. What exactly do you mean? I just try to start the Activity in the onCreate Method with startActivtiy(intent). It would be redudant to show three onCreate methods where I just start another Activity. Or what exactly are you interested to see?

Comment: We can't tell you why your function fails without seeing your code. You don't need to post the first two you mentioned, if don't see that they are related to this problem, but (as already said) we can't identify the cause of the third function's failure without having seen its code.

Comment: I edited my post. I had commented out everything from my code. I just try to start new activities. I think also that the mistake is not in the MapsActivity, because it is working fine. But I have also no idea what is the beginning of the problem. I would like to show you more code, but no idea where to start...